# Xcode AppIcon 'x' and 'L' symbols

Tags: xcode, xcasset, ios-icons

just wondering what do these symbols mean in .xcassets?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the order of your image, those symbols identifies respectively:

1. **Crossed circle:** App icons for both iOS and watchOS;
2. **Circled L:** launch images.

For your reference these are the other symbol Xcode uses:

[image]

1. **Circled AppStore symbol:** App icons for OS X apps;
2. **Crossed circle:**  App icons for both iOS and watchOS;
3. **Empty square:** standard asset (for any platform);
4. **File symbol:** generic OS X icons.

Comment: Thanks, way better than my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

- **Simple square:** standard asset
- **Crossed square:** App Icon
- **Rounded "L":** Launch image